# Cumulative sums with data.table and multiple by conditions

Tags: r, data.table, cumsum

I have been fighting with cumsum to work with multiple conditions. In this case I need to perform a running temperature sum for each day of the year for `year`, `site`, `canopy` and `treatemt_abbr`. Here is sample of the simplified data:

```
  site year doy canopy power treatment_abbr airtemp_comb_nearby gdd10
  cfc 2009   1 closed     0             h2          -18.153490     0
  cfc 2009   2 closed     0             h2           18.153490     8
  cfc 2009   3 closed     0             h2           13.153490     3
  cfc 2009   1 open       0             ac           12.490        2
  cfc 2009   2 open       0             ac           16.912620     6
 hwrc 2012   1 closed     0             dc           11.146437     1
 hwrc 2012   2 closed     0             dc            2.005500     0
 hwrc 2012   3 closed     0             dc            2.5500       0
 hwrc 2012   4 closed     0             dc            22.1234      12
 hwrc 2012   5 closed     0             dc            2.005500     0
```

my actual data set is quite large, so I am wanting to use the data.table functionality. It seems to me that following should work. It does create the new column "gddsum10", but fails to do the running sum. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
dt[order(doy), gddsum10:=cumsum(gdd10), by=c("year", "doy", "site", 
                                             "canopy", "treatment_abbr")]
```

I am looking for something along the lines of this with the new column `"gddsum10"`:

```
  site year doy canopy power treatment_abbr airtemp_comb_nearby gdd10    gddsum10
  cfc 2009   1 closed     0             h2          -18.153490     0     0
  cfc 2009   2 closed     0             h2           18.153490     8     8
  cfc 2009   3 closed     0             h2           13.153490     3     11
  cfc 2009   1 open       0             ac           12.490        2     2
  cfc 2009   2 open       0             ac           16.912620     6     8
 hwrc 2012   1 closed     0             dc           11.146437     1     1
 hwrc 2012   2 closed     0             dc            2.005500     0     1
 hwrc 2012   3 closed     0             dc            2.5500       0     1
 hwrc 2012   4 closed     0             dc            22.1234      12    13
 hwrc 2012   5 closed     0             dc            2.005500     0     13
```

Comment: I assume that the problem is that you specified `doy` as one of the grouping variables, which is not what you actually want, according to the desired output. What if you remove it from the `by` argument?

Comment: I just sat down to look at this again after some coffee... I saw the doy issue right away... duh! Thanks for the comment however. Next time I'll get coffee before posting.

Comment: Probably not an exact duplicate but after the third time looking at the question, I just snapped and _needed_ it closed, since it was clear that the answer was already obtained. I think the linkage to the other cognate question with several good answers is a benefit to future searchers after truth.